# How to restrict single UIViewController in iOS 10 universal app to portrait layout?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have an iOS 10 universal app (supports both iPad and iPhone). In the application .plist I have specified that the app supports both portrait and landscape mode. Now I would like to restrict a single UIViewController to portrait only mode. That view controller is presented by the same navigation controller that presents other view controllers. What is the best (easiest) way to restrict a single, specific view controller to portrait in iOS 10.  (Note that there are lots of published solutions, but as far as I can tell the answer to this problem is is different for different versions of iOS. I only need a solution that supports iOS 10.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I would like to restrict a single UIViewController to portrait only mode. That view controller is presented by the same navigation controller that presents other view controllers

In iOS 10, there is *no* supported way to do what you're describing. A navigation controller cannot have some of its children in one orientation and other children in another.

The only supported way to have a view controller force a different orientation is to make it a *presented* view controller (modal), *not* a pushed view controller in a navigation controller stack.